# Going from dual boot to single boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, clone

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed in a dual boot with Windows 10 on a single 500GB SSD. I use Grub to choose which OS to boot into. The drive has a boot partition, then a Windows NTFS partition, then Ubuntu.

As the drive is running low on space, I've just installed a 250GB M2 drive in the machine.

Can I clone either the Windows or the Ubuntu partition onto the new drive, delete the redundant partition (and extend the leftover OS into the newly emptied space) and then use Grub to choose which OS to boot?

For my first (rather naive) attempt, I used Macrium Reflect to clone just the Windows partition onto the new M2 drive. But predictably when I tried to boot off this new drive, I got a "grub error" prompt. Then I tried updating grub from Ubuntu, which recognised the new OS installation but appears to just boot straight back off the old drive (presumably because it shares the same UUID as the M2 drive).

Any thoughts/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: In BIOS, there is an option to give boot priority to drives. Placethe drive where Windows is installed in the first position and check whether it is still bootable. If not then try windows boot repair / recovery. Make sure that the windows is bootable before using the `sudo apt update-grub`. After this you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks. I tried making the new drive first priority, but that's when I got the grub error. Of course, with no Ubuntu installation on that drive, I think grub is confused. And I don't think I can invoke the Windows boot repair tool unless I can get into the new installation of Windows. I can invoke it from the old installation but can't tell it to repair the new installation. Does that make sense?

Comment: To follow up: I managed to fix the boot sector of the new drive (with the cloned Windows on it) using Boot-repair-disk. The new Windows clone boots fine if I disconnect the old drive. However, I need the old drive connected to boot Ubuntu. If I use grub from the old disk, it refuses to boot Windows off the new disk! It always reverts back to the old Windows installation left on the old disk (presumably it has the same UUID?). Is there any way for me to tell grub how to differentiate between these 2 Windows installations?

Comment: in the `/boot/efi/EFI` directory, there will be a folder named Microsoft. This folder is responsible for all the windows entries in the grub. If there are multiple directories named Microsoft, then find the one that represents the older one and delete that. If there is one then try your best to remove the traces of the older. In my case, I removed windows completely, but still Windows boot manager would appear in the grub menu. So I deleted this directory named Microsoft and the menu entry for the windows boot manager disappeared

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason there's nothing in my "boot" folder on Windows. There's not EFI folder at all, in either of my Windows OS partitions. (We're talking about on the Windows system drive, right?) HOWEVER... I did work out that I could change the UUID of both the boot partition and the OS partition on the new drive using Gparted, which is what I've done. Then I updated Grub2 and I'm now able to boot into either of my Windows installations. Are there any issues with changing the UUID of the Windows partitions?

Comment: try that with a live boot. Not sure about the UUID doubt

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go. Been using new clone of Windows all day today and no problems, so fingers crossed the UUID thing won't cause any problems.